# Bringing a service in android into the foreground

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android service where I don't want that the phone disables the services automatically.
I therefore try to put a notification into the notifcation bar.
When I try to do so my HTC Hero reboots.

I use the following code, what's wrong? It's partly copied from the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).
Is there a good tutorial that explains how this API works?

```
private static final Class<?>[] mSetForegroundSignature = new Class[] {
    boolean.class};
private static final Class<?>[] mStartForegroundSignature = new Class[] {
    int.class, Notification.class};
private static final Class<?>[] mStopForegroundSignature = new Class[] {
    boolean.class};

private NotificationManager mNM;
private Method mSetForeground;
private Method mStartForeground;
private Method mStopForeground;
private Object[] mSetForegroundArgs = new Object[1];
private Object[] mStartForegroundArgs = new Object[2];
private Object[] mStopForegroundArgs = new Object[1];

void invokeMethod(Method method, Object[] args) {
    try {
        mStartForeground.invoke(this, mStartForegroundArgs);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // Should not happen.
        Log.w("ApiDemos", "Unable to invoke method", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // Should not happen.
        Log.w("ApiDemos", "Unable to invoke method", e);
    }
}

/**
 * This is a wrapper around the new startForeground method, using the older
 * APIs if it is not available.
 */
void startForegroundCompat(int id, Notification notification) {
    // If we have the new startForeground API, then use it.
    if (mStartForeground != null) {
        mStartForegroundArgs[0] = Integer.valueOf(id);
        mStartForegroundArgs[1] = notification;
        invokeMethod(mStartForeground, mStartForegroundArgs);
        return;
    }

    // Fall back on the old API.
    mSetForegroundArgs[0] = Boolean.TRUE;
    invokeMethod(mSetForeground, mSetForegroundArgs);
    mNM.notify(id, notification);
}

/**
 * This is a wrapper around the new stopForeground method, using the older
 * APIs if it is not available.
 */
void stopForegroundCompat(int id) {
    // If we have the new stopForeground API, then use it.
    if (mStopForeground != null) {
        mStopForegroundArgs[0] = Boolean.TRUE;
        try {
            mStopForeground.invoke(this, mStopForegroundArgs);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // Should not happen.
            Log.w("ApiDemos", "Unable to invoke stopForeground", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Should not happen.
            Log.w("ApiDemos", "Unable to invoke stopForeground", e);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Fall back on the old API.  Note to cancel BEFORE changing the
    // foreground state, since we could be killed at that point.
    mNM.cancel(id);
    mSetForegroundArgs[0] = Boolean.FALSE;
    invokeMethod(mSetForeground, mSetForegroundArgs);
}

private void setupNotification(){
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        mStartForeground = getClass().getMethod("startForeground",
                mStartForegroundSignature);
        mStopForeground = getClass().getMethod("stopForeground",
                mStopForegroundSignature);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // Running on an older platform.
        mStartForeground = mStopForeground = null;
        return;
    }
    try {
        mSetForeground = getClass().getMethod("setForeground",
                mSetForegroundSignature);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "OS doesn't have Service.startForeground OR Service.setForeground!");
    }

    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.notification_active_text);
    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    startForegroundCompat(
            R.string.foreground_service_started, 
            notification);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, it should not reboot, but the code from the sample has at least 2 major bugs and will not work as expected. I've tested it with Android 1.6 emulator and it worked for me only after the following changes:

1. **invokeMethod()** is obviously wrong because it ignores the passed arguments and makes a fixed method call instead. IntelliJ IDEA spots this problem easily and the fix would be changing `mStartForeground.invoke(this, mStartForegroundArgs);` to `method.invoke(this, args);`
2. **onCreate()** in the [original sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ForegroundService.html) will not initialize **mSetForeground** on 1.6 since **return** statement is in the first **catch**, while it must be in the first **try** instead. You'll get an NPE when trying to start the service. Removing **return** after `mStartForeground = mStopForeground = null;` and placing it after `mStopForeground = getClass().getMethod("stopForeground", mStopForegroundSignature);` will fix this problem.

**UPDATE:** Looks like Google has already fixed [the sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ForegroundService.html) and it should work fine out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

google didn't fix the issue .
what worked for me is putting this in the beginning instead of what they use:

```
private static final Class<?>[] mSetForegroundSignature   = new Class[] {Boolean.TYPE};
private static final Class<?>[] mStartForegroundSignature = new Class[] {Integer.TYPE, Notification.class};
private static final Class<?>[] mStopForegroundSignature  = new Class[] {Boolean.TYPE};
```